# Error code in javascript

Tags: javascript

Why does this code not work?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head></head>


<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
  if(document.images)
  {
    Narrow=new image
    Parrow=new image

    Narrow.src="C:/N.png"
    Parrow.src="C:/P.png"
  }
  else
  {
     Narrow=""
     Parrow=""
     document.arrow=""
  }
 </script>



<body>
    <A href="google.com" onmouseover="document.arrow.src=Parrow.src" onmouseout="document.arrow.src=Narrow.src">
    <img src="C:/N.png" Name="arrow" border="0" alt="arrow" /></A></body>
```

> line 9 column 6 - Warning: `<script>` isn't allowed in `<html>` elements
>   line 4 column 1 - Info: `<html>` previously mentioned
>   Info: Doctype given is "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
>   Info: Document content looks like XHTML 1.0 Transitional
>   1 warning, 0 errors were found!

**Correct code:**

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"> 
if (document.images)
{
 img_N =new Image();

  img_N.src ="C:/N.png";


 img_P=new Image();

  img_P.src="C:/P.png";


    }
 function mouseOverImage()
{
    document.arrow.src = img_P.src
}
function mouseOutImage()
{
    document.arrow.src = img_N.src
}

 </script>

<body>

  <A href="google.com" onmouseover="mouseOverImage()" onmouseout="mouseOutImage()">
<img src="C:/N.png" name="arrow" border="0" alt="arrow" /></A>
</body>
```

Comment: Maybe because `img` elements cannot have a `name`? You could tell us the error you get...

Comment: Hi: you need to state your question clearer: explain what you are trying to do, what is not working, and what the error messages are.

Comment: And *which* line in your file is line 9? And really, nothing personal, but you *can* read, can't you? “Warning: `<script>` isn't allowed in `<html>` elements”

Answer (score 1):

```
Narrow=new image
```

should be

```
var Narrow = new Image();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should wait for the document to load before attempting to inspect it, stuff your code in a function and call it in `<body onload="yourFunc()">`

Also js is case sensitive so its `new Image();` not `new image`

If the files are local I would use .`src="file:///C:/N.png";`

Answer (score 0):

For a start you need a semicolon after every javascript command, you haven't closed the html tag, and it isn't really clear what you're trying to do.

If you are just trying to change the image when the mouse is over it, then this will work (if the image source is valid):

```
<body>
<a href="google.com" onmouseover="document.arrow.src='C:/P.png'" onmouseout="document.arrow.src='C:/N.png'">
<img src="C:/N.png" name="arrow" border="0" alt="arrow" />
</a>
</body>
```

Comment: Then what are you trying to do?